# TypeError: 'Status' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, twitter, trust

I am trying to use the code I share below to fetch the user data and tweets.

```
def get_all_tweets(screen_name):

    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    #initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []

    #make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum   allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
    

    #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1]["id"] - 1
```

Everything seems to be set up well, but when I run the code, I get this error:

```
<ipython-input-7-2ce84a05eaae> in get_all_tweets(screen_name)
    110 
    111     #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
--> 112     oldest = alltweets[-1]["id"] - 1
    113 
    114 

TypeError: 'Status' object is not subscriptable
```

Why is 'Status' non-subscriptable? And is there a way I can fix this issue?

Someone please help me!

Comment: `Status` objects aren't subscriptable because the class doesn't implement `__getitem__()`. You have no control over this because `Status` is defined in the API. You _could_ monkeypatch the class, but this will probably introduce bugs if you aren't familiar with the tweepy source code. You can probably access the id using the dot operator: `alltweets[-1].id`.

Answer (score 0):

`Status` objects aren't subscriptable. The code must access their attributes via the dot operator:

```py
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
```